# Unauthenticated sources, what does this mean?

Tags: windows

I tried to go on a website and it said, "this page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources". Will someone please explain to me what "unauthenticated sources" mean. And if it is safe to go on that site or not? I would appreciate the help. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

#### **"This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources"**

The warning indicates that some of the content on the page you are trying to load is being loaded from a website that is not secure (it is not using an encrypted connection).

---

#### Is it safe to go on that site?

There can be a risk using such a connection, for example passwords may be
transmitted as plain text and not encrypted and can maybe intercepted.

It is not advisable to override the warning. Do so at your own risk.

---

#### Why am I seeing this warning?

You will see this warning if you are trying to access a website that is using HTTPS and some of the content is coming from a website that is using HTTP.

> **Issue**
>
> Websites that ask for sensitive information, such as usernames and
> passwords, often use secure connections to transmit content to and
> from the computer you're using.
>
> If you're visiting a site via a secure connection, Google Chrome will
> verify that the content on the webpage has been transmitted safely.
>
> If it detects certain types of content on the page coming from
> insecure channels, it can automatically prevent the content from
> loading and you'll see a shield icon Insecure content shield icon
> appearing in the address bar.
>
> By blocking the content and possible security gaps, Chrome protects
> your information on the page from falling into the wrong hands.
>
> **What to do if you see this alert**
>
> Parts of the page may not display when Chrome blocks the insecure
> content. You might want to notify the website owner that their site
> isn't properly secured, particularly if it does not display properly.
>
> Although not recommended, you can choose to override the alert for the
> page by clicking Load unsafe script. Chrome will refresh the page and
> load its content, including any insecure content. The URL in the
> address bar will show [image: https crossed] out to indicate that the
> page is not fully secure.

Source ["This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en)

---

#### What is the difference between HTTPS and HTTP?

> - HTTPS (also called HTTP over TLS, HTTP over SSL, and HTTP Secure) is a protocol for secure communication.
> - HTTP is insecure and is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle and eavesdropping attacks, which can let attackers gain access to website
>   accounts and sensitive information, and modify webpages to inject
>   malware or advertisements. HTTPS is designed to withstand such attacks
>   and is considered secure against such attacks

Source [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Difference_from_HTTP)